# Is $l^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ a Hilbert space when provided with a variation of the regular inner product?

Tags: functional-analysis

I have to see if the mentioned space is Hilbert with the following inner product:
\begin{equation*}
\langle a,b\rangle := \sum \lambda_k a_k b_k
\end{equation*}
where $\lambda_k \in (0,1)\ \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$.

My guess is that one can construct a certain instance of the $\lambda$ sequence such that there is a sequence of sequences that is Cauchy according to the metric induced by this inner product, but not by the regular $l^2$ metric, such that this sequence does not converge, thus proving that this space is not always Hilbert, but i haven't been able to find such an example.

Comment: Are you asking if the norm is equivalent to the usual norm or if the resulting space is Hilbert? If you take $\lambda_k = { 1\over k+1}$, then the unit vectors $e_k$ are not Cauchy with the usual norm, but are Cauchy with the "$\lambda$" norm.

Comment: If you are just asking if the resulting space with that inner product is Hilbert, then is is easy to demonstrate a bijective isometry between $l_2$ and the resulting space and hence it is Hilbert.

Comment: Is this really an inner product? It doesn't look positive-*definite*.

Comment: Oh, my bad, this was a misunderstanding on my part. (I'm used to French notations, so I misinterpreted $(0, 1)$.)

Answer (score 1):

For any choice of $\{\lambda_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ with your conditions, $\langle~,~\rangle$ is an inner product. A Hilbert space is *defined* as a complete inner product space, so if we take the space of all sequences and complete it with respect to this new inner product, then we will obtain a Hilbert space.

I believe that your question is really whether these Hilbert spaces are subsspaces of the Hilbert space obtained by completion with respect to the inner product with $\lambda_k=1~\forall k\in\mathbb{N}$. This is not true. For instance, let $\lambda_k = k^{-\varepsilon}$ and consider the sequence $x_k = k^{-1/2}$. With respect to this inner product, we have $$\|x\|^2 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{1+\varepsilon}}
<\infty.$$ However, $\{x_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ has infinite norm when all $\lambda$'s are equal to one.

Answer (score 0):

If $\lambda_k\ge x>0$ for some $c,$ then $$\sqrt{c} \|x\|\le \|x\|_\lambda\le\|x\|$$ where $\|\cdot \|$ denotes the standard norm in $\ell^2(\mathbb{R})$ while $\|\cdot\|_\lambda$ denotes the modified norm.

If $\inf_n\lambda_n=0$ there exists an increasing sequence of indices $n_k$ such that $\lambda_{n_k}\le 8^{-k}.$ Let $$x_n=\begin{cases} 2^k &n=n_k \\ 0 & {\rm otherwise}\end{cases}$$ Then $\|x\|_\lambda^2=1$ while $\|x\|=\infty.$

Let $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be the standard basis in $\ell^2.$ Obviously any subsequence is not a Cauchy sequence with respct to the standard norm as $\|e_n-e_m\||^2=2$ for $n\neq m.$ However $\|e_{n_k}\|_\lambda^2=8^{-k}\to 0$.